# Ordinal Logistic Regression in python and Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, statsmodels

I have been trying to import `statmodels` (https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/ordinal_regression.html#Probit-ordinal-regression:) to google colab without success.

I tried `pip install statmodels` which worked but then when I tried to import the ordinal model following the code from the above website:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats

from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel
```

The following error message came up:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model'`

I have tried to follow the instruction from https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/install.html but I am not sure what went wrong, please help, thank you so much

[image]

Comment: looks like statsmodels main (and next release) requires python 3.8 or later. Try to pip update statsmodels to get the release 0.13.x version.

Answer (score 0):

The module location has changed to `from statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model import OrderedModel`